# What is non PV work? How is it related to Gibbs energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

Recently, I was trying to understand more about Gibbs free energy and got stuck at this point. Some books write that if $\Delta G=0$, then the reaction is reversible while some other sources say that a reaction is reversible when  $\Delta G$ = Non-$PV$ work.
I am not able clarify things here and am unable to understand the core concept of non $PV$ work.

Answer (score 8):

At **constant temperature and pressure**, the maximum non expansion work is given by the change in the Gibbs Free Energy.

$$dW_{\text{max}}= dG$$

**Proof:**

At constant temperature and pressure,

- from the definition of enthalpy: $H= U+pV$
- first law of thermodynamics: $dU = dq+dw$

$\implies dH = dq+ dw + d(pV)$

Now,

$dG = dH - TdS -SdT \\\implies dG = dq + dw + d(pV)- TdS - SdT$

For isothermal process $dT =0$

$\implies dG = dq+dw+ d(pV)+ -TdS$

When the change is reversible,

$dq = dq_{\text{rev}}= TdS$ and $dw= dw_{\text{rev}}$

$\implies dG = dw_{\text{rev}}+d(pV)$

The work consists of expansion work, which for a reversible change is given by
−pdV, and possibly some other kind of work (for instance, the electrical work of
pushing electrons through a circuit or of raising a column of liquid); let's denote it by $dw_{\text{add},\text{rev}}$

$\implies dG= dw_{\text{add}, \text{rev}}+ Vdp$

For isobaric process, $dp =0$

$\implies dG = dw_{\text{add}, \text{rev}}$

You must be aware the the **maximum work is obtained when the process is reversible**, if not you may refer to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14012/why-is-the-maximum-work-achieved-in-reversible-processes).

$\implies dG = dw_{\text{add}, \text{max}}$

> Some books write that if $\Delta G=0$, then the reaction is reversible while some other sources say that a reaction is reversible when  $\Delta G$ = Non-$PV$ work.

$\Delta S_{\text{total}}= \dfrac{-\Delta G_{\text{system}}}{T}$

Thus, for a reversible process $\Delta G_{\text{sys}}= 0$

And I have also proved to you above that $\Delta G_{\text{sys}}=$ maximum non expansion (non PV) work.

> I am not able clarify things here and am unable to understand the core concept of non $PV$ work.

PV work is only the work done during the *change in volume*. There can be different types of works that a system can do during a process, for instance: [electrical work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(electrical)), work against gravity, work against friction, magnetic work, shaft work, etc. This is the concept of non expansion or non PV work.

**Source:**

- Physical Chemistry by Atkins (8th ed. )
- [Wikipedia article on work in thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(thermodynamics))

Comment: You proved $\Delta G_{sys=0}$ but also proved that $\Delta G_{sys}=$ maximum non expansion work , does that imply maximum non PV work=0?